# How to format time data type in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, time, php-carbon

How can I format time data type in laravel? Please see my code below.

**Model**

```
protected $dates = ['start_date', 'end_date', 'show_at', 'hide_at', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

**View**

```
{{ $promotion->show_at->format('h:i:s A') }}
```

**Data from database (type: time)**

```
23:59:59
```

**Error**

> Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try:

```
{{ Carbon::parse($promotion->show_at)->format('H:i:s') }}
```

Comment: Holy cow! Didn't expect this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this  :

```
{{ date_format($promotion->show_at,"h:i:s A") }}
```

Comment: This works as well. Except that you have to use `\DateTime` class. :)

Comment: @Jonjie, yes, you are using the same but in `Object oriented style` &  I give you `Procedural style` https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php